# What does でもわかる mean and what does あって+か do?

Tags: grammar

> 丸い顔と丸い頬は幼い容貌を形作り、**そのせいもあってか**、**服の上からでもわかる**くらい豊かに成熟している胸元にはつい目を引き寄せられてしまう。

What does あって+か do in this sentence?

Also what meaning does でもわかる have in this sentence? Is the でも being used as "even"?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope the following helps.

その せい も あって か "(partly and/or maybe) because of, (among other reasons)"

服の上からでも わかる "noticeable even when the girl is clothed"

Comment: What if it were just そのせいもあって instead of そのせいもあってか. What would be the difference?

Comment: @Tomm: If you drop か, you mean you have no hesitation to "predicate." Thus I would say, by just dropping "maybe," "(partly) because of, (among other reasons)."